# Using Arrays.copyOfRange() for below API 9

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app which uses the method `copyOfRange(byte[] original, int start, int end)` from `Arrays.copyOfRange()`.

It has been introduced in only for API 9 and above. But, I have read somewhere that internally it uses `System.arraycopy()` which has been introduced in API 1 itself.

My question is, in Android, is there a difference in using `Arrays.copyOfRange()` or `System.arraycopy()` and if I am able to use System.arraycopy() will it work for lower versions of APIs???

Also, if I could get some sample code on copying a byteArray using `System.arraycopy()`.

Regards.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Arrays.copyOfRange() is just a convenience method for System.arrayCopy()

```
public class ArraysCompat {
    public byte[] copyOfRange(byte[] from, int start, int end){
        int length = end - start;
        byte[] result = new byte[length];
        System.arraycopy(from, start, result, 0, length);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I used this function as internal function instead of calling it as `System.arraycopy()`. Now, my app runs from API level 7 and onwards. One thing to be corrected is the correct case in method name, the name reads as 'arraycopy' not 'arrayCopy'. I will correct that in my question as well.